# Caml query builder Office 365 Sharepoint Online

Tags: caml-query, sharepoint-online, office-365

Does anyone knows where to find a CAML query builder that I can use for Office 365, Sharepoint Online?
(if there exists one)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 2 popular CAML query tools are [Strammit CamlViewer](http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/) and [U2U CAML Builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx).  They both say they're for 2007, but it's been proven they work fine for 2010 versions as well.

Edit: and the [BIWUG CAML Designer](http://www.biwug.be/resources) works for O365 too.

Comment: The problems with these are that I can't login in Office 365 ...

Comment: U2U you should be able to as you point it to a URL and can provide login credentials.

Comment: But I also need to fill in a domain. Any idea what to fill in there?

Comment: when you login on the web site, do you login like something\username?  if so, that something is the domain.  on my public 2010 site, it's ems\username, so using U2U, I'd put in ems as the domain.

Comment: No, to login we use an e-mail address and a password. We don't have to fill in a domain

Comment: it looks as if when a MS Online site is created it needs a domain and based on that domain, it creates the site like contoso-1.microsoftonline.com.  Look at your URL and look to see what value in your URL looks like that and that should be your domain to use.

Comment: Apparently these don't support MFA, at least cannot login to any SPOs that have MFA enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Its an old question, but i will update for my finding..

there is [SPCAMLQueryHelper](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/)

it has choice for office 365, i have tried it and its works :)

[image]

edit : in field username you should fill your email for o365 account, ex : username@mysubs.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: I've used this, very comfortable and straightforward.

Comment: Not working, might be due to MFA, can anyone confirm?

Comment: Yes facing issue due to MFA

Answer (score 1):

For the reference, people trying to find the same thing
they can use http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/caml-designer/

Select Client Object Model in settings

Comment: Download links behind the link are dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QuickCAML, it is a very good tool for quickly authoring and testing CAML queries in SharePoint 2010 and 2013 (including SPO / Office 365).

How to use the QuickCAML see:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FY2IehUjuc

Download link: https://github.com/sapientcoder/QuickCAML

Comment: This is the only one that works with MFA enabled SPO sites, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

[Saketa CAML Query Builder](https://saketa.com/sharepoint-caml-query-builder/) is a CAML query generator for any version of SharePoint and other object models alongside, that help to retrieve data from the SharePoint lists/ libraries.

Comment: Using this app requires registration, didn't do it, so cannot comment if it works.

Comment: registration does not work. It sucks.

Answer (score -2):

you can build your query while coding. check this cawl4SharePoint it is open source class.
There are even extra features in it.

https://github.com/makdeniz/cawl4SharePoint

Comment: shameless self-plugs without disclosure are frowned upon, even if it *is* open source.