# Does SharePoint Online Browser work for You?

Tags: tools

I get errors and cannot connect using SharePoint Online Client Browser, version 1.11.0.0 (I used this old version, because newer had a bug)

Same behaviour with "U2U CAML Query Builder".

Is it my problem, or something changed on SharePoint Online side? What solutions do You use instead of SPCB and 'U2U CAML Query Builder'?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most probably related to all of the classic CAML tools (not only U2U) not supporting MFA. I [tested](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27754/caml-query-builder-office-365-sharepoint-online/243204#243204) all of them few weeks back and none of the Windows desktop CAML query apps worked. Only one I got working in SPO was [QuickCAML](https://github.com/sapientcoder/QuickCAML).

QuickCAML instructions say ASPX should be copied to Wiki library, but it worked fine in Publishing Pages library as well.

For SPCB I have no comments as I haven't tested it.