# CAML error when querying SharePoint List for more than one input

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, content-type, error, caml-query

I have a `CAML` query which retrieves data from a `SharePoint` list. It passes for 1 input, but fails when there are 2 or more.

**Error:**

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: One or more field types are not
>   installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these
>   fields. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: One or more
>   field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page
>   to delete these fields.
>
> ---

After researching, probable cause may be due to mismatch SharePoint column `InternalName` . However, query managed to execute for 1 input, but not 2 or more.

Base on the query examples below, am I having a wrong format for the `FAIL` cases?

---

**1. PASS:**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

---

**2. FAIL:**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <And>
                <Or>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Or>
                    <Neq>
                        <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
                    </Neq>
            </And>
        </Eq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

**3. FAIL:**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <And>
                <Or>
                    <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
                    <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value>
                </Or>
                <Neq>
                    <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
                </Neq>
            </And>
        </Eq>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: try caml query builder https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27754/caml-query-builder-office-365-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 1):

First of all check the [internal names](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) and data types of your fields you are using in your CAML query, Accordingly your queries will change.

If all your internal names are correct then try using below queries:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

This will return the results when:

`Header1Ref` is equal to "H1" or "H2" **AND** `ContentType` is not be equal to "Document".

**official documentation**: [Query Schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema).

**Update**:

If you are using OOTB `ContentType` field then you need to query on it like below:

1. Using Content Type Name:

```
<Neq>
    <FieldRef Name="ContentType"/><Value Type="Computed">Document</Value>
</Neq>
```

2. Using Content Type ID:

```
<BeginsWith>
   <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId"/><Value Type="ContentTypeId">YourContentTypeIdHere</Value>
</BeginsWith>
```

Comment: Hi @Ganesh, I have checked that the internal names are correct, and the query for just a single `Header1Ref` does returned result. This error occurred when there are more than one `Header1Ref` value. I executed the query that you provided but encountered the same error as well.

Comment: Are you using OOTB Content Type field or you have created a custom field for content type?

Comment: Also, is the data type of `Header1Ref ` is single lines of text?

Comment: @gymcode Have you tried this? Is it working for you??

Answer (score 0):

**2. Try:**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value>
                </Eq>
            </Or>
            <Neq>
                <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
            </Neq>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```

**3. Try:**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value>
                </Eq>
            </Or>
            <Neq>
                <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
            </Neq>
        </And> 
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 0):

In both number 2 and 3 you have `And` operators that only contain one test. It can be helpful to replace your tests with boolean values to better see how the queries will behave. 
Example for number 2:

```
Where
  And
    And         
      (True or True)
      False
```

The second `And` says that `Header1Ref` should be equal to either "H1" or "H2", and `ContentType` should not be equal to "Document".

The first `And` compares the result of the second `And` and nothing else. This is why it fails.

In number 3 you are also missing comparison operators inside your `Or` statement.

I think the following query will achieve what you are trying to do:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H1</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Header1Ref"/><Value Type="Text">H2</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name ="ContentType"/><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```